# Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 Resources

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I am planing to switch operating systems (I'm currently using Windows 7 x64) from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

My main reason why I am switching to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is to try my luck with it. Currently Windows 7 really consumes a lot of CPU and RAM. If we're going to look at it who consumes less CPU and RAM, is it Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04?

Additional Info.

- Both OS are running on the same hardware Specifications
- AMD A6 APU Dual Core with 2.7GHZ
- 8 GB of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 requires a minimum of 1000 Mhz processor with 1GB of RAM, while Ubuntu requires a minimum of 700 Mhz processor with 384MB RAM. While these are the official requirements, in practice, the requirements are considerably higher. From my experience, If you install both the operating systems on identical hardware, Ubuntu’s performance is significantly higher than that of Windows 7.
In fact, if you were to pull out a 7 year old computer from a junkyard, Ubuntu will work flawlessly.
Moreover, the boot time of Ubuntu is considerably less than its Windows 7 counterpart.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this from real life experience, I had Windows 7 installed for a long time, on Core 2 Duo 2.4Ghz, with 8 GB RAM, and it had an OK performance.  I installed Ubuntu 11.04 at the time, in a virtual machine, and that did a major performance drop.  Now since I made Ubuntu my main OS, and I'm still running 12.04LTS, same hardware, with 4 virtual machine, one of which is Windows 7, and its like a dream.  Same performance as with just a fresh installation of Ubuntu.  Oh, all 4 VM run at the same time.  So to end this, Ubuntu will perform much better than windows. (personal opinion).

Comment: does ubuntu uses less CPU and less RAM?

Comment: In general yes.  But then again you might use an application, that might just use a lot of CPU and RAM.  For me it Windows 7 inside a VM, when I run it by itself, I can see more CPU and RAM being used.

Answer (score 0):

My experience:

I used to have Windows 7 in a virtual machine with 1GB RAM. It was used mainly for firefox and few other applications. It worked ok, never had any performance problems.

Now I installed Ubuntu 14 LTS. It doesn't function with 1GB RAM at all. Open firefox, open youtube, open google maps, it comes to a still. Needs 2GB at least. On a bright side, I don't need to use mouse anymore. Just need to learn all those command line switches. Reminds me of my VAX/VMS youth. What shelf is that "ls" manual on?